# Converting webpages from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in linux

Tags: linux, encoding, character-encoding

Anyone have a neat trick on how to convert a number of php and html files from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in linux (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ubuntu has [recode](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/recode)

```
$ sudo apt-get install recode
$ recode UTF-8..latin1 *.php
```

Recursively, thanks to [Ted Dziuba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104/ted-dziuba):

```
$ find . -name "*.php" -exec recode UTF-8..latin1 {} \;
```

Comment: recode is a fairly standard Linux program - not so standard that it's always installed by default, but it should be available on all distributions, not just Ubuntu.

Comment: Recursively, it's find . -name "*.php" -exec recode UTF-8..latin1 {}\;

Comment: +1 Found your answer while searching google for this conversion. It saved my day :)

Comment: To do it with all files in a directory recursevely from ISO to UTF:
`find "$F" -name "*" -exec recode latin1..UTF-8 {} \;`
Where $F is the path to the files.

Comment: To confirm which @DavidZ said - it's also available in Cygwin

Answer (score 10):

I think iconv is your answer...

Form man iconv:

```
  NAME
      iconv - Convert encoding of given files from one encoding to another

  SYNOPSIS
      iconv -f encoding -t encoding inputfile

  DESCRIPTION
      The iconv program converts the encoding of characters in inputfile from one coded 
      character set to another. The result is written to standard output unless otherwise 
      specified by the --output option.

      .....
```

So you could probably do a

```
find $my_base_dir -name "*.php" -o -name "*.html" -exec sh -c "( \
   iconv -t ISO88592 -f UTF8 {} -o {}.iconv ; \
   mv {}.iconv {} ; \
)" \;
```

This will recursively find the appropriately named files and re-encode them (the temporary file is necessary, as iconv will truncate output before starting to work).